# Google Apps Script - Create variables dynamically within an array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, dynamic

## **GOAL:**

**Dynamically create and populate separate arrays with only a specific TYPE of meat** -
console.log(beef_meat_array);
Returns only -

['Rump Fillet','Rump Steak', 'Ground Chuck']

console.log(lamb_meat_array);
Returns only -

['Cutlets']

console.log(chicken_meat_array);
Returns only -

['Drumsticks', 'Breasts']

console.log(fish_meat_array);
Returns only -

['Red snapper', 'Salmon', 'Tilapia']

**CODE BEING RUN**

```
  var types_of_meat = [
   ['Beef', 'Rump Fillet'],
   ['Beef', 'Rump Steak'],
   ['Beef', 'Ground Chuck'],
   ['Lamb', 'Cutlets'],
   ['Chicken', 'Drumsticks'],
   ['Chicken', 'Breasts'],
   ['Fish', 'Red snapper'],
   ['Fish', 'Salmon'],
   ['Fish',  'Tilapia']
 ];


  //this creates a function to create an array of the indicated "column"
  const arrayColumn = (arr, n) => arr.map(x => x[n]);

  //this creates a function that only has unique values
  function onlyUnique(value, index, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) === index;
    }

  //following array is of ONLY the first column, TYPES of meat, from the types_of_meat array
  var meat_type_array = arrayColumn(types_of_meat, 0);
  //following array is of ONLY the unique values of TYPES of workouts
  var unique_meat_types = meat_type_array.filter(onlyUnique);

  for (i = 0; i <= types_of_meat.length - 1; i++)
  {
    eval("var " + unique_meat_types[i] + "_meat_array = " +  types_of_meat.filter(e => e[0] == unique_meat_types[i]));
  }
```

**ACTUAL RESULT**

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Fillet'

The reason this needs to be dynamic is that statically defined arrays will need to be added to. E.g. if types of pork are added to the main array, then a separte explicitly defined array would need to be created.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [hashmap](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with keys as meat names and values as array.

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
  var types_of_meat = [
   ['Beef', 'Rump Fillet'],
   ['Beef', 'Rump Steak'],
   ['Beef', 'Ground Chuck'],
   ['Lamb', 'Cutlets'],
   ['Chicken', 'Drumsticks'],
   ['Chicken', 'Breasts'],
   ['Fish', 'Red snapper'],
   ['Fish', 'Salmon'],
   ['Fish',  'Tilapia']
 ];
 const meatArrayMap = types_of_meat.reduce(((a,c)=>((a[c[0]]??=[]).push(c[1]),a)),Object.create(null));
 console.log(meatArrayMap)
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @TheMaster...damn...that works. Neophyte programmer so, while aware of hashmaps, never played around with them. I'm looking to reference the arrays in other portions of the code, is this possible with hashmaps?

Comment: @Southern-Remove Yes. `meatArrayMap.Beef` to get Beef array. Look into objects in mdn